# storing directory size into integer variable using c++

Tags: c++, linux, directory

Below is my C++ code in which I am trying to store size of a Directory into integer variable

```
char path[60];
char exec[180];
sprintf(path,"%s","/home/Directory");
sprintf(exec,"du %s",path);
int k;
k = system(exec);
printf("\n Value = %d\n",k);
```

and the output is

```
556 /home/Directory
 Value = 0
```

It is not storing in K

Here we can store output to a file using either

```
sprintf(exec,"du %s" > file.txt,path);
sprintf(exec,"du %s >> file.txt",path);
```

But again we have to open that file(file.txt) and read data into variable.

My question is there any other alternative to store the size of a directory into integer variable Kindly suggest me is there any alternative 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You should read [the `system` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html). And then you might want to read about [`popen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html).

Comment: You'll need a `pipe()` to access output of a child process. You can't actually do this with a `system()` call.

Comment: `popen` will do what you want, and works very well for this sort of thing - as long as you are only after "one direction at a time".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as Joachim & Mats explained, do something like this.

Below code is for your reference only!

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int MAX_BUFFER = 2048;
char path[60];
char cmd[180];
sprintf(path,"%s","/home/Directory");
sprintf(cmd,"du /home/Directory",path); 
char buffer[MAX_BUFFER];
FILE *stream = popen(cmd, "r");
if (stream)
{
   while (!feof(stream))
   {
        if (fgets(buffer, MAX_BUFFER, stream) != NULL)
        {
           //...
        }
   }
   pclose(stream);
}
```

Comment: atol(buffer) will convert from char array to integer as I requested
Thank you very much